# Sqlx not throwing error when scanning into invalid type

Tags: mysql, go

I am using sqlx in Go, which is very helpful, but it does not seem to throw errors when I use struct scan and the types of the struct don't match the sql types. For example here I set up a database to have a name (string) and age(int):

```
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| name  | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| age   | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
+------+-----+
| name | age |
+------+-----+
| bob  |  10 |
+------+-----+
```

I then use sqlx to read out the values into a struct, but the struct has the wrong types.

```
package main

import (
  "log"
  "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
  _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

// in database name is a string and age is an int

type Person struct{
  Name int
  Age string
}

func main() {
  sqlSession, err := sqlx.Open("mysql", "root:@(localhost:3306)/dashboard?parseTime=true")
  if err != nil {
    log.Panic(err)
  }
  err = sqlSession.Ping()
  if err != nil {
    log.Panic(err)
  }
  query := "SELECT * FROM test"
  rows, errSql := sqlSession.Queryx(query)
  if errSql != nil {
    log.Panic(errSql)
  }
  for rows.Next() {
    var p Person
    errScan := rows.StructScan(&p)
    if errScan != nil {
      log.Panic(errScan)
    }
    log.Println("Person:", p)
  }
}
```

So instead of giving me an error, it has zeroed out values. Person: {0 }

Has anyone else run into this problem? Does any one else think this is a bug? I think it should give me an error when I try to scan into an invalid type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that is a side-effect of deciding not to return errors when it can't find a place to put the returned value.  One reason you may not want to return an error is if you do a "select *", then even if your struct has all columns, you will not be able to add new columns without the code immediately beginning to return errors.

One could argue that if *all* the query columns were unused, then it should return an error.  Probably opening an issue with the project would be the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try to open and issue and see how it goes.